# Count taking forever

Tags: sql, t-sql, count

I'm not a T-SQL Extrodinare, I'm an App Dev guy.  With that I can't figure out why this count is taking forever.

```
select  p.Code,
    count(p.Head) as HeadCount,
        p.Wt
from Povs p
left outer join Sales s on SheetKey = p.SheetKey
left outer join Site [site] on [site].CompanyKey = s.CompanyKey
left outer join Lot lot on lot.LotID = s.LotID
group by lot.LotID, [site].SiteKey, Code, Wt
```

Povs has around 115749000 records in it.

Comment: and the other tables, how many ros they have?. There are a lot of rows, how many time is "forever" ?

Comment: forever meaning I've left this thing running for 5 minutes already, that seems like a lot to me...

Comment: there are 160,000 records in sales, 3000 in lot, 700 in site approx

Comment: Have you tried adding the `WITH(NOLOCK)` hint? Realizing of course that your numbers will be prone to phantom reads.

Comment: Why are you grouping by more columns than are in your select list?

Comment: It would also help to add the tables' definitions (including indexes) and the execution plan.

Comment: "Why are you grouping by more columns than are in your select list?" because lot is one of the dimensions of this query, but I don't necessarily need to return it back in the select itself.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: And then how do you distinguish two rows in the result with same `Code` and `Wt` but different `lotID` or `SiteKey`?

Comment: well one problem is the damn server ran out of disk space um duh that could be it LOL.

Comment: ypercube, I am not sure.  how would you do that, I'm not that great at SQL, would be helpful to know, good point.  I guess some kind of multikey that I could generate on the fly with another field that would allow me to compare..that might be one idea?

Comment: As it was mentioned above, let me point out that slapping `NOLOCK` on this query is very likely not to improve anything, and might introduce spurious errors that you cannot fix. I wish that old recommendation would finally die.

Comment: hmm why would it spur errors?

Comment: Google for "nolock data movement". It is an error condition only occurring under read uncommitted isolation level.

Answer (score 1):

Unless that is not the real query this is a problem

```
left outer join Sales s on SheetKey = p.SheetKey
```

SheetKey = p.SheetKey is always going to return true so that is a join of every row in Sales

115,749,000 X 160,000 = 18,519,840,000,000 rows in that join

Why are you joining Lot?  You can drop that join and group by s.LotID

Use same syntax.  If you are going to [] then be consistent. If I use joins I always use the two part name.   Why alias Lot to lot?

Comment: Since he doesn't use an alias in the first sheetkey, the engine won't use Sheetkey from Sales table?

Comment: @ElVieejo If SheetKey was in Sales then would get the following error Msg 209, Ambiguous column name 'SheetID'  Please try it for yourself.  Any column name must be unique.  Name alone is unique only if it is in only one table.